# HTML form for login always returns null values in request parameters

Tags: java, servlets

I don't know why am I stuck in something this simple, but I just cant get out of it.

First the HTML file I am using

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Welcome Guest- Please Login</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

function validate() {

    username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    password = document.getElementById("password").value;

    if( username==null || username=="" ) {
        alert("Please enter a username");
        return false;
    }

    if( password==null || password=="" ) {
        alert("Please enter a password");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="login" method="POST">
    <br />
    Name: 
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
    <br />
    Password: 
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" onclick="return validate()" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And the doPost() method of my servlet

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    UserLoginDAOImplementation usr = new UserLoginDAOImplementation();

    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");

    System.out.println(username + password);
    User u = usr.getPassword(username);

    if( u.getPassword().equals(password)) { // If password matches

        response.sendRedirect("images");
    } else {
        response.sendRedirect("invalid");
    }
}
```

I have searched the internet for all kinds of queries but nothing works. I know there is the problem of enctype and all and I have tried that too along with numerous other experiments. Every time I run this, those print statements just print `nullnull` and null pointer exception is thrown. I am really really stuck with this. Please someone tell me what is wrong.

I am using Eclipse Juno with Tomcat and other Java EE plugins.

EDIT:

Just like i suspected, problem was somewhere else entirely. I simply run my program today without even touching the previous code and it worked like a charm. I dont even know what the hell was wrong yesterday.
 I am new to eclipse and i am noticing such behavior from eclipse again and again since i started using tomcat. I had to restart eclipse to make it render changes i made in html files for which i would love to have a work around. I restarted eclipse several times with this problem but it was not working at all. 
**So can you please guide me with some tips to be remembered while working with web applications in eclipse...**

Comment: before sending your username and password to servlet check whether javascript gets that value (TRY) - console.log(username) and console.log(password)

Comment: yes they are getting the values as the script wont let the form submit with null fields.

Comment: how are u binding html inputs with `UserLoginDAOImplementation` attributes?

Comment: I didn't really get you techexchange.. What exactly do you mean by binding?? 
And my problem lies before that. Notice the print statements i included. They print null, hence no data is getting into the servlet at all.

Comment: Let's exclude the client or server from being the suspect. First, press F12 in Chrome/IE9/Firebug and check "Network" section while submitting the form. Are the username/password present as request parameters?

Comment: Follow approach mentioned by BalusC . You can also try changing method from "POST" to "GET" temporarily to see what is being passed on in the request from the browser URL itself

Comment: Ok so i wasted 3 hours yesterday just trying to figure out what the hell is wrong and i just came to my seat this morning only to find out that its working perfectly fine. So i guess it has gotta be some sort of misbehavior from eclipse which i must understand for problems like this in future.

Comment: I guess you needed to publish the changes in eclipse to Tomcat to sees the changes. I thought by default this happens automatically and one has to change the configuration to make "manual publish" necessary, but maybe this has changed meanwhile.